# Add a pause to temporarily disable clicks

Tags: javascript, events, pause

I'm making a quick script to reveal my girlfriend's present, which I can't deliver in person. I want to add a pause in between clicks, so she can't accidentally go through all cases in a second.

```
var gifty = document.getElementById("gift");
var counter = 4;

var handler = function() {
  gifty.style.backgroundPosition = counter * 722 + "px " + "0px";
  counter -= 1;
  switch (counter) {
    case 3:
      document.getElementById("head2").innerHTML = "Click it again! Click it again!";
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById("head2").innerHTML = "Hmmm, what could it be?";
      break;
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("head2").innerHTML = "Any ideas what it could be?";
      break;
    case 0:
      document.getElementById("head2").innerHTML = "Surprise! Your new sewing mahcine is waiting for you in Doha! Hope you like it. xxxxx";
      gifty.removeEventListener("click", handler);
      break;
  }
}

gifty.addEventListener("click", handler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `setTimeout` to toggle the click handler:

```js
const PAUSE_DURATION = 2000 // 2 seconds

const gifty = document.getElementById('gift')
const header = document.getElementById('head2')
const setText = text => header.innerHTML = text

let counter = 4

const handler = () => {        
  counter -= 1
  
  switch (counter) {
    case 3: setText('Click it again! Click it again!  '); break
    case 2: setText('Hmmm, what could it be?  '); break
    case 1: setText('Any ideas what it could be?  '); break
    case 0: setText('Surprise! Your new sewing machine is waiting for you in Doha! Hope you like it.  '); break
  }
  
  removeClickHandler()
  
  setTimeout(() => addClickHandler(), PAUSE_DURATION)
}

const addClickHandler = () => gifty.addEventListener('click', handler)
const removeClickHandler = () => gifty.removeEventListener('click', handler)

addClickHandler()
```

```html
<div id="gift">
  <h2 id="head2"> Click here! ❤️ </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var initialTime = new Date().getTime();

var handler = function() {
    var clickTime = newDate().getTime();
    if (clickTime - initialTime > 1000) { // 1 second

         (... do your stuff here ...)

       initialTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```